# MailChimp API: How do I retrieve mc:edit names and values for a campaign?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm connecting to the MailChimp API using the [PHP Marketing library.](https://github.com/mailchimp/mailchimp-marketing-php)
I have a custom template I created which has some `mc:edit` divs. The code below updates the values and is working properly:

```
$response = $mailchimp->campaigns->create([
    "recipients" => [
        "list_id" => "11111111",
    ],
    "type"=>"regular",
    "settings" => [
        "subject_line" => date("F j, Y, g:i:s a"),
        "from_name"    => "Peter Griffin",
        "reply_to"     => "peter@familyguy.com",
        "template_id"  => 123456,
    ],
]);


$response = $mailchimp->campaigns->setContent($response->id, [
    "template"=> [
        "id"=> 123456,
        "sections"=> [
            'location_name'=>'The Moon',
            'location_address'=>'1234 Moon St',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

I want to retrieve the section names and values e.g. `location_name`, `The Moon`, `location_address`,`1234 Moon St` for a campaign.

How can I do this through the API?
I could retrieve the HTML content and then scrape for the `mc:edit` values but it seems too messy.